# I have searched every post but I could not solve my error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
package com.books.bookstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myAccount")
    public String myAccount() {
        return "myAccount";
    }
}
```

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.6.RELEASE
         
    
    com.bookstore
    bookstore
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    bookstore
    This is the description of my project.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

http://localhost:8081/myAccount

Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Apr 01 14:36:39 EAT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Please complete your question. It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: what is the error that you receive ?

Comment: Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Apr 01 14:36:39 EAT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: what is URL for api call you are making ?

Comment: Thanks for responding Mr. Hemant KUMAR http://localhost:8081/myAccount

Comment: Does this "com.books.bookstore.controller" package comes ComponentScan?

Comment: Please do edit it better also. This is java, right? So put a Java tag so people can find this post more easily. You should also use triple ticks instead of indentation for code, while also specifying the language you're using. And this post shows no clear boundaries between code and text, with code not even properly highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to return view from these controller methods like - index.html/index.jsp

Configure view resolver in your project. Here is good article around it.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial

Also, if you just need to return JSON response from your APIs then add annotation 
@ResponseBody on top of your method like -

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
```

P.S. - It is good practice to use appropriate HTTP methods in your APIs

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

**Edit:**

- instead of using `@RequestMapping` with the `method` parameter, you can use `@GetMapping`
- if this is a REST controller instead of adding `@ResponseBody` to every method, annotate the class with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.

*P.J.Meisch*

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr KUMAR.

Comment: my problem started after adding @RequestMapping(value = "/myAccount")
 public String myAccount() {
  return "myAccount";
 }

Comment: I have made some changes as you suggested but still I get the same error

Comment: I wanted import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

Answer (score 0):

Using `@GetMapping` is another easy solution

```
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: I want to thank everyone for help. it finally worked.